# What can cause my Creality K1 Camera not to be shown in Creality Cloud?

Tags: creality, creality-k1, camera

I bought a Creality K1 3D printer and used it without any problems, with great results, so I decided to buy a camera, specific to the model, which is capable of showing in real time how the print is going and generating timelapses. When it arrived, I installed it and opened the Creality cloud website, where I can see my printer information online, and the camera was detected but kept loading infinitely.

I tried to contact support but the information they gave me was like: restart the machine, disconnect and connect the camera, reinstall the firmware, change the WiFi. I tried all of this and nothing worked, I decided to download the "standard" slicing app for this printer, the Creality slicer, I configured the printer and was able to connect it via IP and see the information, to my surprise the camera works in the slicer app, but not on the website, so the camera is working correctly, and the problem could be a connection problem between my printer and Creality Cloud, I would like to know if there could be some type of port or IP permission, or firewall that is preventing the printer from sending the camera image to the website.

Comment: Do you have administrative access to the router and what router brand and model do you have?